# custom of setting the corpse adrift

Tags: terminology

I read a custom of setting a corpse in water; this was read in a novel Moby Dick. What do we call the custom of setting the corpse adrift in the sea? Is there any particular name of this custom?

Comment: "Setting adrift" suggests that the corpse floats on the surface. Traditionally in Britain the corpse is stitched up in sailcloth together with some weights to ensure that it sinks. The Wiki article that RubioRic describes refers two methods that are permitted by Islam: one involves using stones to make the corpse sink: the other involves tying it between two planks to make it float, in the hope that it will reach land so that the remains can be buried properly, facing Mecca.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are talking about a **[burial at sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burial_at_sea)** [wikipedia]

> **Burial at sea** is the disposal of human remains in the ocean, normally
>   from a ship or boat. It is regularly performed by navies, and is done
>   by private citizens in many countries.

For those that do not read the comments thoroughly, @James K has found a web page where you can read an excerpt of Moby Dick (by Herman Melville) *with a quite detailed description of a burial at sea*

[The Pequod Meets the Delight](http://www.powermobydick.com/Moby131.html)

Comment: Moby dick does include a quite detailed description of a burial at sea, when the *Pequod* meets the *Delight* when the http://www.powermobydick.com/Moby131.html